# Does wp_redirect keep the referrer?

Tags: wp-redirect

I'm monitoring traffic from Google, and if the traffic source is google, I want them redirected to the same URL, but with an appended GET variable, such as http://example.com/article should be redirected to http://example.com/article?source=google

I have hooked in to the hook wp, and added an action to check the referrer. If the referrer is google, it redirects them to the 2nd version of the URL. Unfortunately I'm developing locally and can't really test the referrer properly, so I'm wondering, as far as google analytics, and other tracking services, will the referrer stay as Google with wp_redirect, or will the referrer be changed to my own site?

I am using a 302 redirect.

Comment: This article shows that it's kept http://www.atlantaanalytics.com/practicing-web-analytics/how-does-google-analytics-handle-301-and-302-redirects/

Any other conflicting issues here with WordPress?

Comment: So, you run WordPress and redirect to same page running again WordPress for the same task and same visit/visitor. I think you should think again about what you want to do and how it should be done.

Comment: That's why I'm here, to get advice from others. Yes, I'm trying to serve two versions of the same page, as a split test. However if google indexes ?version=1 first, then the split test is majorly skewed and version 1 will show as the winner, when in fact, it was just indexed first.

I'm trying to prevent this from happening by saying "If the visitor is from google, clear out the version number, and pick a new one. If the one picked is not the one linked to, then redirect them to that version, but track the referrer"

Comment: My advise is to not make a redirect. Just pick up the referrer and use [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter to choose a different template if the user comes from Google. You will gain in performance. By the way, if Google notes that you are serving different content for the search engine you will be banned.

Comment: There are two versions of the same article, the only difference is the title, and featured image. I do not need a new template for this, but it might be an option. Version 1 is standard, and will be sent to users and google, version 2 will be randomly sent to users. There will be a 302 redirect from ver 1 to ver 2 for the users, and a canonical tag if we decide to change the URL. The content in the search engine will not be different. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into templates for this.

Comment: In that case, you can use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to set the query for a different post avoiding also the redirection. Or use [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter to change the title of the post, or [wp_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) filter to change the title of the document. In any case, I would avoid the redirection, but it is up to you, I don't know the exact context of your work.